# I can view a WPF ComboBoxItem with Visibility = Collapsed. Is it a WPF bug?

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

If I set a `ComboBoxItem Visibility` to `Collapsed` then I cannot see it when I open the dropdown menu ... but I can select it using keys! Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
<Window x:Class="ComboTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>Element 1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Element 2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed">Collapsed Element</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If I disable the element I still can select it pressing the key C. Is there any way to hide it without removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my second attempt at answering this question. The first was based on the method described here: http://blog.elgaard.com/2009/09/03/wpf-making-combo-box-items-disabled-also-when-accessed-using-the-keyboard/ , which didn't work for the use case described in the question.

Further prodding around Google confirms that this is a fairly ancient bug:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/23b4b0e9-c33b-4353-80e8-5735051aa921/how-can-i-disable-comboboxitems-for-keyboard-input?forum=wpf

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/baa9d1ff-8afa-46c0-8981-9144622c0074/wpf-combobox-disable-items?forum=wpf

The best solution from those pages is a pretty ugly codebehind kludge:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" SelectionChanged="myComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem>Element 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Element 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed" IsEnabled="False">Collapsed Element</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.myComboBox.SelectedItem == null) return;

    ComboBoxItem cbi = this.myComboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.myComboBox.SelectedItem) as ComboBoxItem;

    if (cbi != null && cbi.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            this.myComboBox.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
        }
        else
        {
            this.myComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

This resets the SelectedItem to the previous selection whenever a disabled ComboBoxItem becomes SelectedItem.

Answer (score 0):

This sure looks like a bug to me! A simple alternative would be to bind to an ObservableCollection and manipulate the ObservableCollection to not include that item at all.